# Open questions about automorphism tower theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory

Joel Hamkins has left four open questions about automorphism tower theorem in his wonderful paper [Every group has a terminating transfinite automorphism tower.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9808014)

In fact, the four questions are "For which ordinals $\gamma$ is there a group whose tower becomes centerless in exactly -a many steps? Is there a countable group with an uncountable automorphism tower? Is there a finite group with an uncountable automorphism tower? Is there a finite group G such that $G_\omega$ is infinite?"

I'd like to ask that since the paper has been written (which was published in 1999), has there been progress made in answering these four or relative  questions.

*Hamkins, Joel David*, [**Every group has a terminating transfinite automorphism tower**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-98-04797-2), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 126, No. 11, 3223-3226 (1998). [ZBL0904.20027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0904.20027).